# What will be the expression between conformal time and scale factor for $\Lambda$ CDM model (for $k=0$, $\Omega_M + \Omega_\Lambda = 1$)?

Tags: cosmology, astronomy

An approximation of the relationship between the scale factor and time for our universe is given by the following expression:

$\displaystyle a \approx \left (\frac{\Omega_{M_0}}{\Omega_{\Lambda_0}}\right )^{1/3} \sinh^{2/3}\left ( \frac{3 H_0 \sqrt{\Omega_{\Lambda_0}}}{2} \ t \right )$

What will be the expression of scale factor in terms of conformal time?

Answer (score 0):

The conformal time is given by the integral:

$$\eta=\int_0^t \frac{{\rm d}t'}{a(t')}$$

In principle you simply insert your expression for $a(t)$, evaluate the integral to get $\eta(t)$, invert to get $t(\eta)$ and substitute back into $a(t)$ to arrive at an expression for $a(\eta)$. In practice I think you'll find that the integral has a solution which is not analytically invertible, so the best you can do as far as I can see is to evaluate a numerical approximation of $a(\eta)$.

Comment: Thanks Kyle for your kind response. Actually I am new in this field and I have tried to evaluate the value of /eta from the integral equation by using mathematica but it shows error. Can you please help me to elaborate your response regarding this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @MCosmo WolframAlpha is happy to [evaluate it](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+(sinh(Ax))%5E(2%2F3)+dx) so I don't see why Mathematica would fail. I've omitted all the details of the constants, of course.

Comment: See https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/467103/solution-of-friedmann-equation-in-terms-of-conformal-time